# i want to create a graph in php fetching values from database

Tags: php, phpgraphlib

i have a php website which takes input such as employee name,date,in time and out time.now i want create a graph based on date and time.to see the graph that when the employees are on time.

Comment: what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You could easily pull your values from the database and use something like pchart (http://pchart.sourceforge.net/) to chart the data ?

Comment: hi once again this is my code and i want to generate a line chart x axis having date and y axis having intime and outtime ....all these r being fetched by the database so the graph shud b dynamic